# Modal doesn't work if one of the two modals button is made to disappear due to code restriction

Tags: javascript, html, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

1. I have two modal buttons for pricing purpose, one is for lower and another for higher pricing.
2. If someone has paid for the lower product. The lower modal button disappears but he/she can still see the modal button for higher.
3. If someone has paid for the higher product, both modal buttons disappear.
4. Now if the user has not paid at all he/she can see both modal buttons and with my present coding both modals working fine.

```js
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
var modal2 = document.getElementById('myModal2');

var btn = document.getElementById("modalbutton");
var btn2 = document.getElementById("modalbutton2");

var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
var span2 = document.getElementsByClassName("close2")[0];

btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}
 btn2.onclick = function() {
    modal2.style.display = "block";
}

span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
}
span2.onclick = function() {
    modal2.style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
HTML: 

<button class="btn btn-default" id="modalbutton">Purchase low</button>
   <button class="btn btn-default" id="modalbutton2">Purchase high</button>
```

Issue:

1. When the user has paid for low, the low button disappears, but the modal button for higher remains. But on clicking it the modal doesn't open.
2. Error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null at

```
btn.onclick = function() {
      modal.style.display = "block";
    }
```

3. Why it is going for btn and not directly to btn2. How can I rectify this. Thanks.

Comment: btn2 must be null, I guess this could happen if your page is dynamically rendered and the component not created. otherwise I'm not sure tbh, your javascript code looks fine

Answer (score 0):

I think I found an answer of handling the null. So i placed a check,

```
if (btn !== null){
  btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
 }
}else{
  btn2.onclick = function() {
  modal2.style.display = "block";
 }
}
```

The modal opens. 
Afterwards it showed the error, on clicking the event of close. Stating the low button was undefined. so I placed a check for that too

```
if (span !== undefined){
 span.onclick = function() {
 modal.style.display = "none";
 }
}else{
 span2.onclick = function() {
 modal2.style.display = "none";
 }
}
```

This is some sort of handling of error. If someone has better way to handle this. kindly share.